# C++ std::initializer_list data() function error

Tags: c++

I have tried to make a basic `data()` function for the std::initalizer_list type to extract the data from the list. However, when trying it in a basic sum function of `sum({1, 2, 3, 4})`, I get the result `1447450180` instead of `10`:

```
template < typename _Ty > const _Ty *data(const std::initializer_list<_Ty> &_List)
{
    _Ty *data = new _Ty[_List.size()];
    for (typename std::initializer_list<_Ty>::iterator i = _List.begin();
                i != _List.end(); ++i, *data++ = *i);
    return data;
}
```

---

```
int sum(std::initializer_list<int> numbers)
{
    int total = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); ++i, total += data(numbers)[i]);
    return total;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << sum({1, 2, 3, 4});
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: Why do you even need the data function at all? It looks like you're trying to mix Java, C, and C++11 in a bad way.

Comment: @LB-- - To make it easier instead of writing `int sum(std::initializer_list<int> numbers)
{
    int total = 0;
    for(typename std::initializer_list<int>::iterator i = numbers.begin(); i != numbers.end(); ++i){ total += *i; }
    return total;
}`, and to allow elements to be access by index

Comment: You're not making it easier, you're making it more convoluted. It looks like you don't understand iterators very well and you definitely seem to not understand how to use initializer lists.

Comment: @LB--: I understand how to use iterators perfectly well, and, however, I have just started using initalizer_lists.

Comment: @Joseph Do you realize that *every call* to `data()` allocates memory (and leaks it) and then copies over the initializer list contents? This is quite easily the worst way to re-implement [`std::accumulate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 mistakes:

```
for (typename std::initializer_list<_Ty>::iterator i = _List.begin();
            i != _List.end(); ++i, *data++ = *i);
```

You are incrementing the `data` pointer which skips over the previously allocated memory. Create a `count` variable:

```
int count = 0;
data[count++] = *i
```

But right now you are skipping the first element of the loop because you increment first and then dereference. Switch the order around. The final loop should look like:

```
    for (typename std::initializer_list<_Ty>::iterator i = _List.begin();
            i != _List.end(); data[count++] = *i, ++i);
```

[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/rus5rq)

Comment: data is not an array. It is a pointer. It defined as 
_Ty *data

Answer (score 0):

This function

```
template < typename _Ty > const _Ty *data(const std::initializer_list<_Ty> &_List)
{
    _Ty *data = new _Ty[_List.size()];
    for (typename std::initializer_list<_Ty>::iterator i = _List.begin();
                i != _List.end(); ++i, *data++ = *i);
    return data;
}
```

is invalid at least because there is a memory leak. Each time when the function is called it allocates anew memory for the array data and this array is never deleted.

Moreover the function returns pointer beyond the array because inside it the pointer was changed that is it was incremented.

ALso you do not know how to write loops correctly. In this loop you 1) skip the first element of the sequense and 2 try to access beyond the sequence.

```
    for (typename std::initializer_list<_Ty>::iterator i = _List.begin();
                i != _List.end(); ++i, *data++ = *i);
```

The correct loop will look

```
    for (typename std::initializer_list<_Ty>::iterator i = _List.begin();
                i != _List.end(); ++i )  *data++ = *i;
```

The same is valid for the second loop because it is also invalid

```
for(int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); ++i, total += data(numbers)[i]);
```

There vshould be

```
for(int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); ++i ) total += data(numbers)[i];
```

Also I do not see any sense in your invention.

Comment: I tried that first and it didn't work, so I did the loop in my Q, even though I knew it was wrong

Comment: I am afraid it still doesn't work, and to counter `I do not see any sense in your invention.`, I created it so that you would not have to write out an iterator loop, and also so that you could access elements by an index using the `[]` operator on the `data` function

Comment: @Joseph *I created it so that you would not have to write out an iterator loop* -- this exactly the reason most things in the [`<algorithm>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) header exist!

Answer (score 0):

Use simple solutions, not convoluted ones.

```
#include <numeric>
template<typename T>
T sum(std::initializer_list<T> vals)
{
    return std::accumulate(vals.begin(), vals.end(), T{});
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/524ffb543683d901